# how to extend the timeout of azure fuctions using durables?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-durable-functions

let's say I have an orchestrated function that is chaining like that:

```
[FunctionName("E1")] //default timeout of 5 minutes
public static async Task<List<string>> Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Tokyo")); //takes 5 minutes to complete
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Seattle")); //takes 5 minutes complete
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello_DirectInput", "London")); //takes 5 minutes complete

    // should return ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
}
```

now we have three functions
let's say each one needs 5 minutes to complete (on the default azure consumptionl plan) ,people say each function has it has its own timeout so we should have a total of around 15 minutes in order to complete (5+5+5) for all ,however the top level function E1 has only a timeout of 5 minutes.Will it timeout before complete because the total of all sub-functions exceeds its limit of 5?
if E1 orchestrator timedout then does the activities or subfunctions stop if the orchestrator itself timedout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty about durable functions is that it is only active when orchestrating the function. When it reaches `await context.CallActivityAsync` it will start `E1_SayHello` but it won't wait for its completion. Instead the durable function will unload and resume once `E1_SayHello` is completed.

What you are doing is called the [Function chaining pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#chaining) and this behavior I described above is documented there like this:

> Each time the code calls await, the Durable Functions framework checkpoints the progress of the current function instance. If the process or virtual machine recycles midway through the execution, the function instance resumes from the preceding await call.

So no, the durable function won't be active the whole 15 minutes.

Comment: so basically the time spent on each activity doesn't count from the durable function timeout?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed correct

Comment: just one more question ,Does that apply to callsuborchestrators like callactivties like it stops on await or yield?

Comment: Yeah it applies to those as well. Awaiting a sub-orchestrator or activity will suspend the orchestrator until the result comes back.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ,such a helpful people out there